# Loading more than 5 SWF objects on one page

Tags: php, codeigniter, swfobject

I want to load a few flash banners on my single page. 
I'm using swfobject ( http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/ ). When i'm loading these ten banners in traditional way - just static way, often some of them (3-4) are not loaded, just empty field, when I refresh page - there are always some banners not loaded. Is there a way to load them all in a way, that they will work properly? : ) Maybe some asynchronous loading?

I'm using codeigniter and PHP.

I'm trying to load them in that way:

```
<?php foreach($category_res as $results){ ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            var id = <?php echo $results['id'];?>;
            swfobject.registerObject("banner"+id, "9.0.115");
    </script>


   <div class="baner">

            <div class="kreacja" style="padding-top:25px;" onclick="return false;">

            <object id="banner<?php echo $results['id']; ?>" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" >
                <object class="flash_banner" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="<?php echo '/prod_bann/kategorie/'.$results['category_name'].'/'.$results['file']; ?>"></object>
            </object>

            </div>

   </div>
            <?php } ?>
```

**UPDATE**

I've also tried dynamic SWf fiels embedding - but it's even worse. More banners are not loaded, here's code:

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                var id = <?php echo $results['id'];?>;
                var path = "<?php echo '/prod_bann/kategorie/'.$results['category_name'].'/'.$results['file']; ?>";
                swfobject.embedSWF(path, "banner"+id, "300", "120", "9.0.0");
                </script>


<div class="baner">

   <div class="kreacja" style="padding-top:25px;" onclick="return false;">

     <div id="banner<?php echo $results['id']; ?>" >
     </div>

   </div>

</div>
            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I do not see anything related to [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) here.

Comment: @Mihai Iorga - you're right - just updated my code - can you take a look now?

Comment: You mix swfObject way of importing Flash and HTML one. swfObject imports Flash on page with javascript code, not with HTML `<object>` tag. Use one, nor both.

Comment: Please add full code, you are wasting everyone's time.

Comment: @Mihai Iorga Ok - there is my original code. Sorry for problems.